# I want to upload only .jpg and .jpeg file format to upload

Tags: asp.net, regex, html, file-upload

I have this code , Its allowing .gif files also I want to upload only `.JPG` and `.JPEG`

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuAttachment5" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revFile5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fuAttachment5" Enabled="true" ErrorMessage="Invalid File. Please select valid file." ForeColor="Red"
ValidationExpression="^.+\.(?:(?:[jJ][pP][eE][gG])|(?:[jJ][pP][gG]))$">*
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it will solve your problem

```
"^.+\.((jpg)|(JPG)|(jpeg)|(JPEG))$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Validation Expression to follow

```
ValidationExpression="(.*\.([Jj][Pp][Gg])|.*\.([Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg])$)"
```